# C# new not working as expected on derived class-inheritence

Tags: c#, inheritance, method-hiding

Given the following code below. I am wondering why my output is not B A B, but instead B A A

```
class A
{
    public virtual void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public new void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" B ");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A obj1 = new B();
        B obj2 = new B();
        obj2.display();
        A r;
        r = obj1;
        r.display();
        r = obj2;
        r.display();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
//Output:
B
A
A
```

Since r now is a reference to class B(obj2) it should output B, but it is outputting A.

Comment: It's working exactly as most people would expect, so if it's not matching *your* expectations, explain what you were expecting and **why** those were your expectations.

Comment: I already wrote, I am expecting B A B, got output as BAA

Comment: But **why**. You haven't explained your *reasoning*.

Comment: okay reasoning is as follows
1.obj2 will output B because of the new keyword.

Comment: @ShadmanMahmood yes obj2 currently being typed as B will call the `Display` method in B. `r` being type as `A` doesn't see `Display` in B as it's only for type of B. If it would have been an `override` then it would have called it

Comment: @Franck however when r is referenced to B, it is calling A?

Comment: @ShadmanMahmood See my edit, method hiding is all about what type the *variable* is, not what the type its pointing to is

Comment: @BradleyDotNET could you kindly give an example to what you mean by "what type the variable is" ? thankyou.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I got it -THanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how `new` works. It *is* how `override` works.

`new` (Method *hiding*) only works if your **variable type** (note that the actual type is irrelevant) is the derived type. Your second test is just polymorphism, and you need `override` for that.

```
class B : A
{
    public override void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" B ");
    }
}
```

> Side-note, you almost *never* need method hiding.

Comment: I know that, but this is an mcq question, so I am confused about the output

Comment: @ShadmanMahmood No idea what mcq is, perhaps the question is just wrong?

Comment: mcq is a multiple choice question. I want to know why the output is like that. Thats all

Comment: @ShadmanMahmood Errr…. ok. The second paragraph (and the linked duplicates) explain this, you are missing the difference between hiding a method and using polymorphsim